# What is the correct format for time data in chartjs?

Tags: time, chart.js

My chart is plotting x-axis points from Jan 1 1970. My js is below. Is the format of my x-coordinates what is causing the problem, and if so, how can I get these dates right?

```
var chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
type: 'line',
data: {
    datasets: [{ 
    data: [{x:15-04-2018,y:10},{x:16-04-2018,y:20},{x:17-04-2018,y:30}],

    borderColor: '#3e95cd',
    fill: false
  }]},

options: {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            type: 'time',
            unit: 'day' ,
            distribution: 'linear',
            ticks: { source: 'data' },
            time: { displayFormats: { day: 'MMM DD' } }
        }]
    },
    title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'Student Assessment Cluster Scores'
},


} });
```

Answer (score 0):

The date values must be entered as a javascript Date object. Just like the documentation says,

```
data: [{
    x: new Date(),
    y: 1
}, {
    t: new Date(),
    y: 10
}]
```

So in my question, the dates could be represented by:

```
data: [
{x:new date(15-04-2018),y:10},
{x:new date(16-04-2018),y:20},
{x:new date(17-04-2018),y:30}
]
```